# Facial recognition and classifying unknowns with neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

As far as I understand, neural networks aren't good at classifying 'unknowns', i.e. items that do not belong to a learned class. But how do face detection/recognition approaches usually determine that no face is detected/recognised in a region? Is the predicted probability somehow thresholded?

Comment: it will be better if you ask this on https://ai.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Summary

It is true that neural networks are inherently not good at classifying 'unknowns' because they tend to ***overfit*** to the data that they have been trained on, if the underlying structure of the neural network is complex enough. However, there are multiple ways to go about reducing the affects of ***overfitting***. For example, one technique that is used for this is called ***dropout***. Another example can be ***batch normalization***. Despite these techniques, the best way to reduce the affects of ***overfitting*** is to use *more data*.

For the facial recognition example that you have given above, it is common that the models that have been trained have 'seen' a huge amount of data. This means that there are very few 'unknowns' and even if there are, the neural network has learned how to tell if there are facial features present or not. This is because certain structures of neural networks are really good at telling if there is a pattern of features present in the input data. This helps the neural networks to learn if the image that is being input has certain features/patterns in it or not. If the these features are found then the input data is classified as face otherwise it is not.